# How is the ball $B_\epsilon$ definied?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

We have $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and the function $f_a: \mathbb{R}^{2}$->$\mathbb{R}$ definied by: $f_a(x,y) := \begin{cases}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} &\text{ if } (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\a &\text{ if } (x,y) = (0,0)\end{cases}$

Someone told me a hint for my problem: Test many points $(x,y)$ in a small ball $B_\epsilon((0,0))$

My question is: How is this ball $B_\epsilon$ definied?
I only know how to define a ball if a metric $d$ is given.

Comment: What about telling us what is the problem that you want to solve?

Comment: Proving discontinuity in point $(0,0)$

Comment: You have a metric, namely the metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$. This is the same metric underlying the definition of continuity. Partial aside: this problem reminds me of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: What metric do I have?

Comment: Thank you, so we have $B_\epsilon((0,0)) =$ {$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} | d((0,0),(x,y)) < \epsilon$} with the euclidean metric.

Comment: Sorry, the Euclidean metric is $d((x, y), (\hat x, \hat y)) = \sqrt{ |x-\hat {x}|^2 + |y-\hat {y}|^2 }$.

Comment: Don't need to use absolute value if its $()^2$ anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When nothing else is specified, you can assumed they are talking about the standard metric on $\mathbb R^2$, given by
$$
d(X,Y) = \sqrt{(X_1-Y_1)^2 + (X_2-Y_2)^2}.
$$

In that case, the $\epsilon$-ball is given by

$$
B_\epsilon(0,0) = \{ (x,y) \mid x^2+y^2 < \epsilon^2 \}.
$$